# How to get the data of all the pixels of a picture in "react-native"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am learning using "react-native" to build an iOS application. Now there is a demand:

the user select a picture in his album , and the application need all the data of the pixels of this picture.

I try to use "WebView" which only has a "canvas" tag in it to solve this problem, but I do not know how to transmit the data in the WebView to the WebView's father component...

May I need to change a better method to do this thing? Or do you know how to transmit data from the javascript context in the "WebView" to the WebView's father component?

Just an idea or comment is OK~

Thank you very much~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check out the website i  linked below. I was messing around with something similar a couple months ago and ran into a similar problem. The site below had some good pointers.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx